# Evaluation order of parsed tokens in Racket

Tags: parsing, compilation, racket, lexical-analysis, operator-precedence

I'm working on a compiler project and I need to implement functions in a C-ish language:
First off, I'm using the Racket parser tools (http://docs.racket-lang.org/parser-tools/LALR_1__Parsers.html?q=~a)

Anyway, my current rule for function declaration in my grammer is:

```
(fun-declaration 
     [(type-specifier FNCT \( \) compound-stmt) 
      (begin
        $1
        (printf "~nA function is being declared~n")
        $5
        )])
```

My problem is that the compound-stmt is being evaluated before the code in the begin block (that's a place holder print, the actual code has assembly that is irrelevant to the question). This means that any assembly I print to the file for the function setup/header is written AFTER the compound-stmt, where compound-stmt is {code code code...}

How can I get the code in the begin block to evaluate BEFORE the compound-stmt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the code in the begin block to evaluate BEFORE the compound-stmt?

You can't.

The documentation says:

> Each action is Racket code that has the same scope as its parser’s
>   definition, except that the variables $1, ..., $i are bound, where i
>   is the number of grammar-ids in the corresponding production. **Each $k
>   is bound to the result of the action for the kth grammar symbol** on the
>   right of the production, if that grammar symbol is a non-terminal, or
>   the value stored in the token if the grammar symbol is a terminal.

It sounds as if you are attempting to write a one-pass compiler.

The solution to your problem, is to write a two-pass compiler instead.

The first pass is the parsing. The parser must generate a temporary
data structure representing the parsed code (i.e. an abstract syntax tree, AST).
In the second pass you use the tree representation to generate code.

Comment: I worked it out, by simply printing to a string and returning the whole string up the tree instead of printing directly to std out. this way I could simply put the next code token on either the front or the end of that string which effectively let me control the execution order. Cheers.